# Translation of 档案专业人员

Tags: translation

I found this string 档案专业人员 in a Chinese resume. Google translated it as "file professional" but I don't know what the proper word in English for it would be. I'd like to know which are the main duties of a File Professional or File Manager.

What kind of job is it? Is there any alternative translation?
Thanks!

Comment: Is that one for 檔案管理人員?

Answer (score 5):

档案专业人员 in English is "Archivist".

Comment: +1. In my opinion, "档案专业人员" is a very, very poor translation of archivist. "档案员" is precise, concise and much more preferrable.

Comment: I don't know who user238264 is, but that person should be banned from this forum. It is extremeley poor netiquette changing someone's rendering, in this case from simplified to traditional.

Comment: Second thought, why bother... you can have your Taiwanese forum, what do I care.

Comment: While I fully agree that changing the rendering is a *faux pas* on the level of correcting British to American spelling, from what I can see in the edit history, you didn't enter *any* Chinese, and the person merely added the Chinese to make the answer a complete one.

Answer (score 3):

@倪阔乐 was right. Google parses chinese sentences according to phrase frequency. "专业人员" is more frequent than "档案专业", so the whole string was parsed as [档案[专业人员]], which in turn got translated to [File [Professional]]. And that didn't make much sense.

I think the correct parsing should be [[档案专业]人员], since this appeared in a resume. It most likely means that person (人员) graduated from Archival Science (档案专业).

Answer (score 0):

File(data) organization specialist